# How to select specific prerelease versions?

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

I am using `npm info` to get a list of existing versions for our own private artifact lying in a nexus 3 npm repository. For new features we are using prerelease versions.

Below is my complete data set listing all versions that currently exist:

```
[
  '1.7.0',
  '1.7.1',
  '1.7.2',
  '1.7.3',
  '1.7.4',
  '1.7.5',
  '1.7.6',
  '1.7.7',
  '1.7.8',
  '1.7.9',
  '1.7.10',
  '1.7.11',
  '1.7.12',
  '1.7.13',
  '1.7.14',
  '1.7.15',
  '1.7.16',
  '1.7.17',
  '1.7.18',
  '1.7.19',
  '1.7.20',
  '1.7.21',
  '1.7.22',
  '1.7.23',
  '1.7.24',
  '1.7.25',
  '1.7.26',
  '1.7.27',
  '1.7.28',
  '1.7.29',
  '1.7.30',
  '1.7.31',
  '1.7.32',
  '1.7.33',
  '1.7.34',
  '1.7.35',
  '1.7.36',
  '1.7.37',
  '1.7.38',
  '1.7.39',
  '1.7.40',
  '1.7.41',
  '1.7.42',
  '1.7.43',
  '1.7.44',
  '1.7.45',
  '1.7.46',
  '1.7.47',
  '1.7.48',
  '1.7.49',
  '1.7.50',
  '1.7.51',
  '1.7.52',
  '1.7.53',
  '1.7.54',
  '1.7.55',
  '1.7.56',
  '1.7.57',
  '1.7.58',
  '1.7.59',
  '1.7.60',
  '1.7.61',
  '1.7.62',
  '1.7.63',
  '1.7.64',
  '1.7.65',
  '1.7.66',
  '1.7.67',
  '1.7.68',
  '1.7.69',
  '1.7.70',
  '1.7.71',
  '1.7.72',
  '1.7.73',
  '1.7.74',
  '1.7.75',
  '1.7.76',
  '1.7.77',
  '1.7.78',
  '1.7.79',
  '1.7.80',
  '1.7.81',
  '1.7.82',
  '1.7.83',
  '1.7.84',
  '1.7.85',
  '1.7.86',
  '1.7.87',
  '1.7.88',
  '1.7.89',
  '1.7.90',
  '1.7.91',
  '1.7.92',
  '1.7.93',
  '1.7.94',
  '1.7.95',
  '1.7.96',
  '1.7.97',
  '1.7.98',
  '1.7.99',
  '1.7.100',
  '1.7.101',
  '1.7.102',
  '1.7.103',
  '1.7.104',
  '1.7.105',
  '1.7.106',
  '1.7.107',
  '1.7.108',
  '1.7.109',
  '1.7.110',
  '1.7.111',
  '1.7.112',
  '1.7.113',
  '1.7.114',
  '1.7.115',
  '1.7.116',
  '1.7.117',
  '1.7.118',
  '1.7.119',
  '1.7.120',
  '1.7.121',
  '1.7.122',
  '1.7.123',
  '1.7.124',
  '1.7.125',
  '1.7.126',
  '1.7.127',
  '1.7.128',
  '1.7.129',
  '1.7.130',
  '1.7.131',
  '1.7.132',
  '1.7.133',
  '1.7.134',
  '1.7.135',
  '1.7.136',
  '1.7.137',
  '1.7.138',
  '1.7.139',
  '1.7.140',
  '1.7.141',
  '1.7.142',
  '1.7.143',
  '1.7.144',
  '1.7.145',
  '1.7.146',
  '1.7.147',
  '1.7.148',
  '1.7.149',
  '1.7.150',
  '1.7.151',
  '1.7.152',
  '1.7.153',
  '1.7.154',
  '1.7.155',
  '1.7.156',
  '1.7.157',
  '1.7.158',
  '1.7.159',
  '1.11.0',
  '1.12.0',
  '1.12.1',
  '1.12.2',
  '1.12.3',
  '1.12.4',
  '1.12.5',
  '1.12.6',
  '1.12.7',
  '1.12.8',
  '1.12.9',
  '1.12.10',
  '1.12.11',
  '1.12.12',
  '1.12.13',
  '1.12.14',
  '1.12.15',
  '1.12.16',
  '1.12.17',
  '1.12.18',
  '1.12.19',
  '1.12.20',
  '1.12.21',
  '1.12.22',
  '1.12.23',
  '1.12.24',
  '1.12.25',
  '1.12.26',
  '1.12.27',
  '1.12.28',
  '1.12.29',
  '1.12.30',
  '1.12.31',
  '1.12.32',
  '1.12.33',
  '1.12.34',
  '1.12.35',
  '1.12.36',
  '1.13.0-4161.0',
  '1.13.0-4161.1',
  '1.13.0-4161.2',
  '1.13.0-ft.0',
  '1.13.0-ft.1',
  '1.13.0-ft.2',
  '1.13.0-ft.3',
  '1.13.0-ft.4',
  '1.13.0-ft.5',
  '1.13.0-ft.6',
  '1.13.0-ft.7',
  '1.13.0-ft.8',
  '1.13.0-ft.9',
  '1.13.0-ft.10',
  '1.13.0-ft.11',
  '1.13.0-ft.12',
  '1.13.0-ft.13',
  '1.13.0-ft.14',
  '1.13.0-ft.15',
  '1.13.0-ft.16',
  '1.13.0-ft.17',
  '1.13.0-ft.18',
  '1.13.0-ft.19',
  '1.13.0-ft.20',
  '1.13.0-ft.21',
  '1.13.0-ft.22',
  '1.13.0-ft.23',
  '1.13.0-ft.24',
  '1.13.0-ft.25',
  '1.13.0-ft.26',
  '1.13.0-ft.27',
  '1.13.0-ft.28',
  '1.13.0-ft.29',
  '1.13.0-ft.30',
  '1.13.0-ft.31',
  '1.13.0-ft.32',
  '1.13.0-ft.33',
  '1.13.0-ft.34',
  '1.13.0-ft.35',
  '1.13.0-ft.36',
  '1.13.0-ft.37',
  '1.13.0-ft.38',
  '1.13.0-ft.39',
  '1.13.0-ft.40',
  '1.13.0-ft.41',
  '1.13.0-ft-on-angular.0',
  '1.13.0-ft-on-angular.1',
  '1.13.0-ft-on-angular.2',
  '1.13.0-ft-on-angular.3',
  '1.13.0-ft-on-angular.4',
  '1.13.0-ft-on-angular.5',
  '1.13.0-ft-on-angular.6',
  '1.13.0-ft-on-angular.7',
  '1.13.0-ft-on-angular.8',
  '1.13.0-ft-on-angular.9',
  '1.13.0-ft-on-angular.10',
  '1.13.0-perf.0',
  '1.13.0-perf.1',
  '1.13.0-perf.2',
  '1.13.0-perf.3',
  '1.13.0-perf.4',
  '1.13.0-perf.5',
  '1.13.0-perf.6',
  '1.13.0-perf.7',
  '1.13.0-revival.0',
  '1.13.0-revival.1',
  '1.13.0-revival.2',
  '1.13.0-revival.3',
  '1.13.0-revival.4',
  '1.13.0-revival.5',
  '1.13.0-revival.6',
  '1.13.0-revival.7',
  '1.13.0-revival.8',
  '1.13.0-revival.9',
  '1.13.0-revival.10',
  '1.13.0-revival.11',
  '1.13.0-revival.12',
  '1.13.0-revival.13',
  '1.13.0-revival.14',
  '1.13.0-revival.15',
  '1.13.0-revival2.0',
  '1.13.0-revival2.1',
  '1.13.0-user-pdf.0',
  '1.13.0-user-pdf.1',
  '1.13.0-user-pdf.2',
  '1.13.0-user-pdf.3',
  '1.13.0-user-pdf.4',
  '1.13.0-user-pdf.5',
  '1.13.0-user-pdf.6',
  '1.13.0-user-pdf.7',
  '1.13.0-user-pdf.8',
  '1.13.0-user-pdf.9',
  '1.13.0-user-pdf.10',
  '1.13.0-user-pdf.11',
  '1.13.0-user-pdf.12',
  '1.13.0-user-pdf.13',
  '1.13.0-user-pdf.14',
  '1.13.0-user-pdf.15',
  '1.13.0-user-pdf.16',
  '1.13.0-user-pdf.17',
  '1.13.0-user-pdf.18',
  '1.13.0',
  '1.13.1',
  '1.13.2',
  '1.13.3',
  '1.13.4',
  '1.13.5',
  '1.13.6',
  '1.13.7',
  '1.13.8',
  '1.13.9',
  '1.13.10',
  '1.13.11',
  '1.13.12',
  '1.13.13',
  '1.13.14',
  '1.13.15',
  '1.13.16',
  '1.13.17',
  '1.13.18',
  '1.13.19',
  '1.13.20',
  '1.13.21',
  '1.13.22',
  '1.13.23',
  '1.13.24',
  '1.13.25',
  '1.13.26',
  '1.13.27',
  '1.13.28',
  '1.13.29',
  '1.13.30',
  '1.13.31',
  '1.13.32',
  '1.13.33',
  '1.13.34',
  '1.13.35',
  '1.13.36',
  '1.13.37',
  '1.13.38',
  '1.13.39',
  '1.13.40',
  '1.13.41',
  '1.13.42',
  '1.13.43',
  '1.13.44',
  '1.13.45',
  '1.13.46',
  '1.13.47',
  '1.13.48',
  '1.13.49',
  '1.13.50',
  '1.13.51',
  '1.13.52',
  '1.13.53',
  '1.13.54',
  '1.13.55',
  '1.13.56',
  '1.13.57',
  '1.13.58',
  '1.13.59',
  '1.13.60',
  '1.13.61',
  '1.13.62',
  '1.13.63',
  '1.13.64',
  '1.13.65',
  '1.13.66',
  '1.13.67',
  '1.13.68',
  '1.13.69',
  '1.13.70',
  '1.13.71',
  '1.13.72',
  '1.13.73',
  '1.13.74',
  '1.13.75',
  '1.13.76',
  '1.13.77',
  '1.13.78',
  '1.13.79',
  '1.13.80',
  '1.13.81',
  '1.13.82',
  '1.13.83',
  '1.13.84',
  '1.13.85',
  '1.13.86',
  '1.13.87',
  '1.13.88',
  '1.13.89',
  '1.13.90',
  '1.13.91',
  '1.13.92',
  '1.13.93',
  '1.13.94',
  '1.13.95',
  '1.13.96',
  '1.13.97',
  '1.13.98',
  '1.13.99',
  '1.13.100',
  '1.13.101',
  '1.13.102',
  '1.13.103',
  '1.13.104',
  '1.13.105',
  '1.13.106',
  '1.13.107',
  '1.13.108',
  '1.13.109',
  '1.13.110',
  '1.13.111',
  '1.13.112',
  '1.13.113',
  '1.13.114',
  '1.13.115',
  '1.13.116',
  '1.13.117',
  '1.13.118',
  '1.13.119',
  '1.13.120',
  '1.13.121',
  '1.13.122',
  '1.13.123',
  '1.13.124',
  '1.13.125',
  '1.13.126',
  '1.13.127',
  '1.13.128',
  '1.13.129',
  '1.13.130',
  '1.13.131',
  '1.13.132',
  '1.13.133',
  '1.13.134',
  '1.13.135',
  '1.13.136',
  '1.13.137',
  '1.13.138',
  '1.13.139',
  '1.13.140',
  '1.13.141',
  '1.13.142',
  '1.13.143',
  '1.13.144',
  '1.13.145',
  '1.13.146',
  '1.13.147',
  '1.13.148',
  '1.13.149',
  '1.13.150',
  '1.13.151',
  '1.13.152',
  '1.13.153',
  '1.13.154',
  '1.13.155',
  '1.13.156',
  '1.13.157',
  '1.13.158',
  '1.13.159',
  '1.13.160',
  '1.13.161',
  '1.13.162',
  '1.13.163',
  '1.13.164',
  '1.13.165',
  '1.13.166',
  '1.13.167',
  '1.13.168',
  '1.13.169',
  '1.13.170',
  '1.13.171',
  '1.13.172',
  '1.13.173',
  '1.13.174',
  '1.13.175',
  '1.13.176',
  '1.13.177',
  '1.14.0-1263aaaa.0',
  '1.14.0-1294trackingwithreferrer.0',
  '1.14.0-7076reminder.0',
  '1.14.0-7076reminder.1',
  '1.14.0-7076reminder.2',
  '1.14.0-7076reminder.3',
  '1.14.0-7521id.0',
  '1.14.0-7521id.1',
  '1.14.0-7521id.2',
  '1.14.0-7521id.3',
  '1.14.0-7540quit.0',
  '1.14.0-7540quit.1',
  '1.14.0-7540quit.2',
  '1.14.0-7540quit.3',
  '1.14.0-7540quit.4',
  '1.14.0-7676update-mail-tests.0',
  '1.14.0-7676update-mail-tests.1',
  '1.14.0-7676update-mail-tests.2',
  '1.14.0-7807html-title.0',
  '1.14.0-7807html-title.1',
  '1.14.0-7807html-title.2',
  '1.14.0-7807html-title.3',
  '1.14.0-7807html-title.4',
  '1.14.0-7807html-title.5',
  '1.14.0-7852.0',
  '1.14.0-7852.1',
  '1.14.0-7852.2',
  '1.14.0-7852.3',
  '1.14.0-7874logout.0',
  '1.14.0-7874logout.1',
  '1.14.0-7874logout.2',
  '1.14.0-7874logout.3',
  '1.14.0-7874logout.4',
  '1.14.0-7874logout.5',
  '1.14.0-8002price.0',
  '1.14.0-8002price.1',
  '1.14.0-8079tipp.0',
  '1.14.0-8079tipp.1',
  '1.14.0-8079tipp.2',
  '1.14.0-ft.0',
  '1.14.0-ft.1',
  '1.14.0-ft.2',
  '1.14.0-ft.3',
  '1.14.0-ft.4',
  '1.14.0-ft.5',
  '1.14.0-ft.6',
  '1.14.0-ft.7',
  '1.14.0-ft.8',
  '1.14.0-ft.9',
  '1.14.0-ft.10',
  '1.14.0-ft.11',
  '1.14.0-ft.12',
  '1.14.0-ft.13',
  '1.14.0-ft.14',
  '1.14.0-ft.15',
  '1.14.0-ft.16',
  '1.14.0-ft.17',
  '1.14.0-ft.18',
  '1.14.0-ft.19',
  '1.14.0-ft.20',
  '1.14.0-ft.21',
  '1.14.0-ft.22',
  '1.14.0-ft.23',
  '1.14.0-ft.24',
  '1.14.0-ft.25',
  '1.14.0-ft.26',
  '1.14.0-ft.27',
  '1.14.0-ft.28',
  '1.14.0-ft.29',
  '1.14.0-ft.30',
  '1.14.0-ft.31',
  '1.14.0-ft.32',
  '1.14.0-ft.33',
  '1.14.0-ft.34',
  '1.14.0-ft.35',
  '1.14.0-ft.36',
  '1.14.0-ft.37',
  '1.14.0-ft.38',
  '1.14.0-ft.39',
  '1.14.0-ft.40',
  '1.14.0-ft.41',
  '1.14.0-ft.42',
  '1.14.0-ft.43',
  '1.14.0-ft.44',
  '1.14.0-ft.45',
  '1.14.0-ft.46',
  '1.14.0-ft.47',
  '1.14.0-ft.48',
  '1.14.0-ft.49',
  '1.14.0-ft.50',
  '1.14.0-ft.51',
  '1.14.0-ft.52',
  '1.14.0-ft.53',
  '1.14.0-ft.54',
  '1.14.0-ft.55',
  '1.14.0-ft.56',
  '1.14.0-ft.57',
  '1.14.0-ft.58',
  '1.14.0-ft.59',
  '1.14.0-ft.60',
  '1.14.0-ft.61',
  '1.14.0-ft.62',
  '1.14.0-ft.63',
  '1.14.0-ft.64',
  '1.14.0-ft.65',
  '1.14.0-ft.66',
  '1.14.0-ft.67',
  '1.14.0-ft.68',
  '1.14.0-ft.69',
  '1.14.0-ft.70',
  '1.14.0-ft.71',
  '1.14.0-ft.72',
  '1.14.0-ft.73',
  '1.14.0-ft.74',
  '1.14.0-ft.75',
  '1.14.0-ft.76',
  '1.14.0-ft.77',
  '1.14.0-ft.78',
  '1.14.0-ft.79',
  '1.14.0-ft.80',
  '1.14.0-ft.81',
  '1.14.0-ft.82',
  '1.14.0-ft.83',
  '1.14.0-ft.84',
  '1.14.0-ft.85',
  '1.14.0-ft-on-angular.0',
  '1.14.0-ft-on-angular.1',
  '1.14.0-ft-on-angular.2',
  '1.14.0-ft-on-angular.3',
  '1.14.0-ft-on-angular.4',
  '1.14.0-ft-on-angular.5',
  '1.14.0-ft-tracking.0',
  '1.14.0-ft-tracking.1',
  '1.14.0-ft-tracking.2',
  '1.14.0-report-failed-deployments.0',
  '1.14.0-report-failed-deployments.1',
  '1.14.0-report-failed-deployments.2',
  '1.14.0-report-failed-deployments.3',
  '1.14.0-report-failed-deployments.4',
  '1.14.0-report-failed-deployments.5',
  '1.14.0-report-failed-deployments.6',
  '1.14.0-tr-commons.0',
  '1.14.0-tr-commons.1',
  '1.14.0-tr-commons.2',
  '1.14.0-tr-commons.3',
  '1.14.0-tr-commons.4',
  '1.14.0-tr-commons.5',
  '1.14.0-tr-commons.6',
  '1.14.0-tr-commons.7',
  '1.14.0-tr-commons.8',
  '1.14.0-tr-commons.9',
  '1.14.0-tr-commons.10',
  '1.14.0-tr-commons.11',
  '1.14.0-tr-commons.12',
  '1.14.0',
  '1.14.1',
  '1.14.2',
  '1.14.3',
  '1.14.4',
  '1.14.5',
  '1.14.6',
  '1.14.7',
  '1.14.8',
  '1.14.9',
  '1.14.10',
  '1.14.11',
  '1.14.12',
  '1.14.13',
  '1.14.14',
  '1.14.15',
  '1.14.16',
  '1.14.17',
  '1.14.18',
  '1.14.19',
  '1.14.20',
  '1.14.21',
  '1.14.22',
  '1.14.23',
  '1.14.24',
  '1.14.25',
  '1.14.26',
  '1.14.27',
  '1.14.28',
  '1.14.29',
  '1.14.30',
  '1.14.31',
  '1.14.32',
  '1.14.33',
  '1.14.34',
  '1.14.35',
  '1.14.36',
  '1.14.37',
  '1.14.38',
  '1.14.39',
  '1.14.40',
  '1.14.41',
  '1.14.42',
  '1.14.43',
  '1.14.44',
  '1.14.45',
  '1.14.46',
  '1.14.47',
  '1.14.48',
  '1.14.49',
  '1.14.50',
  '1.14.51',
  '1.14.52',
  '1.14.53',
  '1.14.54',
  '1.14.55',
  '1.14.56',
  '1.14.57',
  '1.14.58',
  '1.14.59',
  '1.14.60',
  '1.14.61',
  '1.14.62',
  '1.14.63',
  '1.14.64',
  '1.14.65',
  '1.14.66',
  '1.14.67',
  '1.14.68',
  '1.14.69',
  '1.14.70',
  '1.14.71',
  '1.14.72',
  '1.14.73',
  '1.14.74',
  '1.14.75',
  '1.14.76',
  '1.14.77',
  '1.14.78',
  '1.14.79',
  '1.14.80',
  '1.14.81',
  '1.14.82',
  '1.14.83',
  '1.14.84',
  '1.14.85',
  '1.14.86',
  '1.14.87',
  '2.2.0',
  '2.2.1',
  '2.2.2',
  '2.2.3',
  '2.2.4',
  '2.2.5',
  '2.2.6',
  '2.2.7',
  '2.2.8',
  '2.2.9',
  '2.2.10',
  '2.2.11',
  '2.2.12',
  '2.2.13',
  '2.2.14',
  '2.2.15',
  '2.2.16',
  '2.2.17',
  '2.2.18',
  '2.2.19',
  '2.2.20',
  '2.2.21',
  '2.2.22',
  '2.2.23',
  '2.2.24',
  '2.2.25',
  '2.2.26',
  '2.2.27',
  '2.2.28',
  '2.2.29',
  '2.2.30',
  '2.2.31',
  '2.2.32',
  '2.2.33',
  '2.2.34',
  '2.2.35',
  '2.2.36',
  '2.2.37',
  '2.2.38',
  '2.2.39',
  '2.2.40',
  '2.2.41',
  '2.2.42',
  '2.2.43',
  '2.2.44',
  '2.2.45',
  '2.2.46',
  '2.2.47',
  '2.2.48',
  '2.2.49',
  '2.2.50',
  '2.2.51',
  '2.2.52',
  '2.2.53',
  '2.2.54',
  '2.2.55',
  '2.2.56',
  '2.2.57',
  '2.2.58',
  '2.2.59',
  '2.2.60',
  '2.2.61',
  '2.2.62',
  '2.2.63',
  '2.2.64',
  '2.2.65',
  '2.2.66',
  '2.2.67',
  '2.2.68',
  '2.2.69',
  '2.2.70',
  '2.2.71',
  '2.2.72',
  '2.2.73',
  '2.3.0',
  '2.3.1',
  '2.3.2',
  '2.3.3',
  '2.3.4',
  '2.3.5',
  '2.3.6',
  '2.3.7',
  '2.3.8',
  '2.3.9',
  '2.3.10',
  '2.3.11',
  '2.3.12',
  '2.3.13',
  '2.3.14',
  '2.3.15',
  '2.3.16',
  '2.3.17',
  '2.3.18',
  '2.3.19',
  '2.3.20',
  '2.3.21',
  '2.3.22',
  '2.3.23',
  '2.3.24',
  '2.3.25',
  '2.3.26',
  '2.3.27',
  '2.3.28',
  '2.3.29',
  '2.3.30',
  '2.3.31',
  '2.3.32',
  '2.3.33',
  '2.3.34',
  '2.3.35',
  '2.3.36',
  '2.3.37',
  '2.3.38',
  '2.3.39',
  '2.3.40',
  '2.3.41',
  '2.3.42',
  '2.3.43',
  '2.3.44',
  '2.3.45',
  '2.3.46',
  '2.3.47',
  '2.3.48'
]
```

But it seems that npm can't differ between different prerelease versions:

```
> npm info artifact@">=1.14.0-ft.0 <1.14.0-ft0" version
[
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.23 '1.14.0-ft.23'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.24 '1.14.0-ft.24'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.21 '1.14.0-ft.21'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.22 '1.14.0-ft.22'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.20 '1.14.0-ft.20'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.29 '1.14.0-ft.29'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.27 '1.14.0-ft.27'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.28 '1.14.0-ft.28'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.25 '1.14.0-ft.25'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.26 '1.14.0-ft.26'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.12 '1.14.0-ft.12'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.13 '1.14.0-ft.13'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.10 '1.14.0-ft.10'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.11 '1.14.0-ft.11'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.18 '1.14.0-ft.18'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.19 '1.14.0-ft.19'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.16 '1.14.0-ft.16'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.17 '1.14.0-ft.17'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.14 '1.14.0-ft.14'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.15 '1.14.0-ft.15'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft-on-angular.4 '1.14.0-ft-on-angular.4'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.45 '1.14.0-ft.45'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft-on-angular.5 '1.14.0-ft-on-angular.5'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.46 '1.14.0-ft.46'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft-on-angular.2 '1.14.0-ft-on-angular.2'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.43 '1.14.0-ft.43'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft-on-angular.3 '1.14.0-ft-on-angular.3'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.44 '1.14.0-ft.44'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft-on-angular.0 '1.14.0-ft-on-angular.0'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.41 '1.14.0-ft.41'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft-on-angular.1 '1.14.0-ft-on-angular.1'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.42 '1.14.0-ft.42'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.40 '1.14.0-ft.40'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.49 '1.14.0-ft.49'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.47 '1.14.0-ft.47'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.48 '1.14.0-ft.48'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.34 '1.14.0-ft.34'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.35 '1.14.0-ft.35'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.32 '1.14.0-ft.32'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.33 '1.14.0-ft.33'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.30 '1.14.0-ft.30'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.31 '1.14.0-ft.31'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.38 '1.14.0-ft.38'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.39 '1.14.0-ft.39'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.36 '1.14.0-ft.36'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.37 '1.14.0-ft.37'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.67 '1.14.0-ft.67'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.68 '1.14.0-ft.68'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.65 '1.14.0-ft.65'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.66 '1.14.0-ft.66'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.63 '1.14.0-ft.63'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.64 '1.14.0-ft.64'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.61 '1.14.0-ft.61'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.62 '1.14.0-ft.62'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.69 '1.14.0-ft.69'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.60 '1.14.0-ft.60'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.56 '1.14.0-ft.56'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.57 '1.14.0-ft.57'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.54 '1.14.0-ft.54'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.55 '1.14.0-ft.55'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.52 '1.14.0-ft.52'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.53 '1.14.0-ft.53'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.50 '1.14.0-ft.50'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.51 '1.14.0-ft.51'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.58 '1.14.0-ft.58'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.59 '1.14.0-ft.59'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.83 '1.14.0-ft.83'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.81 '1.14.0-ft.81'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.82 '1.14.0-ft.82'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.80 '1.14.0-ft.80'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.78 '1.14.0-ft.78'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.79 '1.14.0-ft.79'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.76 '1.14.0-ft.76'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.77 '1.14.0-ft.77'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.74 '1.14.0-ft.74'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.75 '1.14.0-ft.75'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.72 '1.14.0-ft.72'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.73 '1.14.0-ft.73'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.70 '1.14.0-ft.70'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.71 '1.14.0-ft.71'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.4 '1.14.0-ft.4'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.3 '1.14.0-ft.3'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.2 '1.14.0-ft.2'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.1 '1.14.0-ft.1'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.0 '1.14.0-ft.0'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.9 '1.14.0-ft.9'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.8 '1.14.0-ft.8'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.7 '1.14.0-ft.7'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.6 '1.14.0-ft.6'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.5 '1.14.0-ft.5'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft-tracking.0 '1.14.0-ft-tracking.0'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft-tracking.1 '1.14.0-ft-tracking.1'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft-tracking.2 '1.14.0-ft-tracking.2'
]
```

Desired result:

```
> npm info artifact@">=1.14.0-ft.0 <1.14.0-ft0" version
[
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.23 '1.14.0-ft.23'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.24 '1.14.0-ft.24'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.21 '1.14.0-ft.21'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.22 '1.14.0-ft.22'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.20 '1.14.0-ft.20'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.29 '1.14.0-ft.29'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.27 '1.14.0-ft.27'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.28 '1.14.0-ft.28'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.25 '1.14.0-ft.25'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.26 '1.14.0-ft.26'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.12 '1.14.0-ft.12'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.13 '1.14.0-ft.13'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.10 '1.14.0-ft.10'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.11 '1.14.0-ft.11'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.18 '1.14.0-ft.18'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.19 '1.14.0-ft.19'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.16 '1.14.0-ft.16'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.17 '1.14.0-ft.17'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.14 '1.14.0-ft.14'
    artifact@1.14.0-ft.15 '1.14.0-ft.15'
    ...
]
```

I would expect no results, because `ft` is not equal to `ft-on-angular` or `ft-tracking`.

How can I achieve to select at least only `ft` as prerelease version?

I have tried the [semver calculator](https://semver.npmjs.com/) with a similar selector (`>=1.0.0-rc.0 <1.0.0-rc0`) and it selects only 1.0.0-rcX. If I update the selector to `>=1.0.0-r.0 <1.0.0-r0` it doesn't match anything.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216429/discussion-on-question-by-cschulz-how-to-select-a-specific-prerelease-version).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short answer:

> *"How can I achieve to select at least only ft as prerelease version?"*

Via the [`npm info`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/view.html) command you will need to:

- Provide this comparator set to match all `-ft` prereleases for the `1.14.0` version:

  ```
  npm info artifact@">=1.14.0-ft.0 <1.14.0-ft-on-angular.0" version
  ```
- Or, provide this comparator set to match all `-ft` prereleases for the `1.13.0` version:

  ```
  npm info artifact@">=1.13.0-ft.0 <1.13.0-ft-on-angular.0" version
  ```
- Or, provide this range composed of two comparator sets to match all `-ft` prereleases for both the `1.13.0` and `1.14.0` versions:

  ```
  npm info artifact@">=1.13.0-ft.0 <1.13.0-ft-on-angular.0 || >=1.14.0-ft.0 <1.14.0-ft-on-angular.0" version
  ```

**Note:** When determining the correct comparator(s) to use for matching specific prerelease versions, it does require an understanding in advance of the complete data set and its sort order by SemVer precedence. Using the following `npm info` command will return a list (sorted by SemVer precedence in ascending order) for all versions available for a given artifact/package:

```
npm info <package_name> versions
```

---

#### Why does the comparator in your OP yield undesired semvers?

> *"I would expect no results, because `ft` is not equal to `ft-on-angular` or `ft-tracking`."* <sup>**1**</sup>

To further understand why the [`npm info`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/view.html) command and your given comparator set of `>=1.14.0-ft.0 <1.14.0-ft0` doesn't yield your desired list of semvers, we need to firstly comprehend what the Semver Specification states in [point #11](https://semver.org/#spec-item-11) regarding precedence rules. For convenience a copy of *point #11* has been provided below:

<sub>**Note:** The numbered list formatting was added by me.</sub>

> *Precedence MUST be calculated by separating the version into major, minor,
> patch and pre-release identifiers in that order (Build metadata does not
> figure into precedence)*.
>
> *Precedence is determined by the first difference when comparing each of
> these identifiers from left to right as follows:*
>
> 1. *When major, minor, and patch are equal, a pre-release version has lower
>    precedence than a normal version. Example: 1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0.*
> 2. *Precedence for two pre-release versions with the same major, minor, and
>    patch version MUST be determined by comparing each dot separated identifier
>    from left to right until a difference is found as follows:*
>
>    - 2.1. *identifiers consisting of only digits are compared numerically and*
>    - 2.2. *identifiers with letters or hyphens are compared lexically in ASCII sort order.*
> 3. *Numeric identifiers always have lower precedence than non-numeric identifiers.*
> 4. *A larger set of pre-release fields has a higher precedence than a smaller
>    set, if all of the preceding identifiers are equal. Example:
>    1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0-alpha.1 < 1.0.0-alpha.beta < 1.0.0-beta < 1.0.0-beta.2
>    < 1.0.0-beta.11 < 1.0.0-rc.1 < 1.0.0.*

Points 1, 2, 3, and 4 are particularly pertinent to your OP because they specifically address precedence rules regarding the *pre-release* field/identifier within a semver.

**What is incorrect about the comparator set you used?**

> ```
> >=1.14.0-ft.0 <1.14.0-ft0
> ```

1. Firstly we should note that this comparator; `<1.14.0-ft0`, requires the range to be less than version `1.14.0-ft0` and your data set does not include a `-ft0` pre-release.
2. However, if a `-ft0` pre-release identifier did exist in your data set, it would be greater than both the exisiting `1.14.0-ft-tracking.2` and `1.14.0-ft-on-angular.0` semvers - hence this is why the results you are getting include all the `-ft-on-angular` and `ft-tracking` pre-releases.

   To illustrate this further consider the sorted list of semvers (in ascending order) below. Note particularly the precedence of the `-ft0` pre-release identifier - it's clearly greater than the others.

   ```
   ...
   '1.14.0-ft.83',
   '1.14.0-ft.84',
   '1.14.0-ft.85',
   '1.14.0-ft-on-angular.0',
   '1.14.0-ft-on-angular.1',
   '1.14.0-ft-on-angular.2',
   '1.14.0-ft-on-angular.3',
   '1.14.0-ft-on-angular.4',
   '1.14.0-ft-on-angular.5',
   '1.14.0-ft-tracking.0',
   '1.14.0-ft-tracking.1',
   '1.14.0-ft-tracking.2',
   '1.14.0-ft0',                <-------
    ...
   ```

   Now if you consider points 2, 3 and 4 above, (i.e. those that I indicated in the excerpt from the Semver Specification point #11), regarding precedence rules it becomes apparent why the pre-release identifiers in your data set are getting sorted in this way:

- Particularly, consider what point 2.2 states;

  > *"[pre-release] identifiers with letters or hyphens are compared lexically in ASCII sort order*".

  Note the zero (`0`) at the end of the `1.14.0-ft0` semver and also zero's position in the ASCII Sort Chart (below). Compare that with the second hyphen (`-`) in the `1.14.0-ft-tracking.2` semver and also the hyphens position in the ASCII Sort Chart. As you can see the zero's (`0`) sort position comes after the hyphen (`-`). This explains why `1.14.0-ft0` gets sorted after `1.14.0-ft-tracking.2`.

---

**ASCII Sort Order Chart:**

For convenience a chart showing the sort order of ASCII characters is shown below:

```
┌─────────┬──────────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬───────┐
│  space  │  -  (hyphen) │  :  │  G  │  T  │  a  │  n  │  }    │
│  !      │  .           │  ;  │  H  │  U  │  b  │  o  │  |    │
│  "      │  /           │  <  │  I  │  V  │  c  │  p  │  {    │
│  #      │  0   (zero)  │  =  │  J  │  W  │  d  │  q  │  ~    │
│  $      │  1           │  >  │  K  │  X  │  e  │  r  │  DEL  │
│  %      │  2           │  ?  │  L  │  Y  │  f  │  s  │       │
│  &      │  3           │  @  │  M  │  Z  │  g  │  t  │       │
│  '      │  4           │  A  │  N  │  [  │  h  │  u  │       │
│  (      │  5           │  B  │  O  │  \  │  i  │  v  │       │
│  )      │  6           │  C  │  P  │  ]  │  j  │  w  │       │
│  *      │  7           │  D  │  Q  │  ^  │  k  │  x  │       │
│  +      │  8           │  E  │  R  │  _  │  l  │  y  │       │
│  ,      │  9           │  F  │  S  │  `  │  m  │  z  │       │
└─────────┴──────────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴───────┘
```

---

#### Additional note

You will have noticed that when using following correct `npm info` command:

```
npm info artifact@">=1.14.0-ft.0 <1.14.0-ft-on-angular.0" version
```

it prints the results to your console formatted like this:

> ```
> artifact@1.14.0-ft.1 '1.14.0-ft.1'
> artifact@1.14.0-ft.2 '1.14.0-ft.2'
> artifact@1.14.0-ft.3 '1.14.0-ft.3'
> ...
> ```

However, if you wanted to reformat the results to form a JSON array, consider piping the output to [AWK](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) then to node.js. For instance utilizing the following compound command:

```
npm info artifact@">=1.14.0-ft.0 <1.14.0-ft-on-angular.0" version | awk -F "'" '{print $2}' | node -e "process.stdin.on('data', function(d) {console.log( JSON.stringify(d.toString().split('\n').filter(Boolean), null, 2) )});"
```

will yield the following reformatted result instead:

```
[
  "1.14.0-ft.1",
  "1.14.0-ft.2",
  "1.14.0-ft.3",
  ...
]
```

---

<sub>**Footnotes:**</sub>

<sup>**1**</sup> <sub>This expectation is somewhat akin to *NOT* expecting numbers `7` and `8` to be returned from this set of eight numbers; `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, when defining the boundaries for the range to be captured as `>=0 <10`.</sub>

---

<sub>For any new readers of this Q&A you may be interested in reading the discussion in the comments [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216429/discussion-on-question-by-cschulz-how-to-select-a-specific-prerelease-version) which took place prior to providing this answer. Props to [@jwdonahue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3150445/jwdonahue) for his valuable input.</sub>

Comment: you don't need the parsing via awk, just add `--json` to the info command.

Comment: @CSchulz - Yes, you're right. The `--json` option does print a valid JSON array when providing a comparator(s) when using a recent version of the npm CLI tool. However that was not the case for some older versions  - the workaround remains applicable for those older versions.